# Given that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(xy)=xf(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then prove that...

Tags: functions, solution-verification, functional-equations

> **QUESTION:** Let $A$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(xy)=xf(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. $$$$
> (a) If $f \in A$ then show that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ $$$$
> (b) For $g,h \in A$, define a function $g\circ h$ by $(g \circ h)(x)=g(h(x))$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $g \circ h$ is in $A$ and is equal to $h \circ g$.

---

**MY ANSWER:** Here's what I have done..

Putting $y=1$ we get $f(x)=f(1)x$.
Say $f(1)=k$ for some $k \in \Bbb{R}$
$\therefore f(x)=kx \text{ }\forall x \in \Bbb{R}$

This is the solution to Cauchy's Functional Equation which takes the form $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. But the problem is the domain of $x$ and $y$ in Cauchy's Equation is $\Bbb{Q}$ while we have $\Bbb{R}$. Therefore we prove $(a)$ as follows -

Say $y=bx$ for some $b \in \Bbb{R}$

$$ax(1+b)=ax+abx$$

$$\implies ax(1+b)=ax+ay$$

This is similar to saying -

$$f(x(1+b))=f(x)+f(y)$$

$$\implies f(x+bx)=f(x)+f(y)$$

$$\implies f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$

Q.E.D. $\square$

Now, I have two questions..
Firstly, is the above proof alright ?
Secondly, how do I solve point $(b)$ ?

$goh(x)$ is simply another way of saying $g(h(x))$, and everyone knows that $goh(x)=g(h(x))$. Then what is the information given based on which we may proceed ?

Thank You for your help in advance..

Comment: You have proved $A=\{x\mapsto kx\mid k\in\mathbb{R}\}$. For part (a) you simple need to check that $f(x)=kx$ satisfies identity $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Comment: For part (b): if $g,h\in A$, then $g(x)=kx$ and $h(x)=\ell x$ for some $k,\ell$. Now you need to check that $h(g(x))=g(h(x))$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your work we know $f(x)=f(1)x=kx$. To show $a)$, note that

$$f(x+y)=k(x+y)=kx+ky=f(x)+f(y)$$

To show $b)$, note that

$$g(h(x))=g(k_hx)=k_gk_hx=(k_g k_h)x$$

Then

$$g(h(xy))=(k_gk_h)xy=x(k_gk_h)y=xg(h(y))$$

Also

$$h(g(x))=h(k_gx)=k_hk_gx=(k_hk_g)x=(k_gk_h)x=g(h(x))$$

We conclude $g(h(x))=h(g(x))\in A$.